# Can google.appengine.api.taskqueue payload argument be query result?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task, datastore

I'm trying to pass a query result to a taskqueue:

```
q = models.Spam.all()
results = q.fetch(10)
taskqueue.add(url='/_ah/queue/do-spams', payload=results)
```

This isn't working.  I either have the argument structure wrong, or payload cannot be result sets.

Comment: As a side note, this is probably a bad idea: entities can be bulky, and there's a limit of 10k on task queue payloads. Deferred will store anything larger in the datastore, so you're not gaining anything over just fetching the records inside your task queue handler. Also, the records could be out of date by the time your task executes.

Comment: @NickJohnson: When we have such a useful deferred library, why do we need or why someone else use taskqueue.add() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding directly to a task queue I would use the deferred [queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html). Deferred Queues have similar functionality as task queues.  One of the key features of deferred queues is that you can pass any type of data to one of your internal methods.

You specify the method you want to defer, the parameter values, and the deferred queue and appengine takes care of passing to data correctly.

Comment: Interesting - totally missed that.  "The deferred library lets you bypass all the work of setting up dedicated task handlers and serializing and deserializing your parameters by exposing a simple function, deferred.defer(). "

Comment: Deferred uses standard task queues, Nick just provided a nice generic wrapper to make this type of application easy.  You could achieve the same thing by, for example, pickling the results and passing them to your task via payload.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the documentation on taskqueue, I suspect that you need to pass a string, or at least a object, that has a string representation.

> The payload data for this Task that will be delivered to the webhook as the HTTP request body. May be a string containing binary data.
>
> http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html#Task

Why isn't it working? Do you get an error? For a quick test you could try to pass it `str(results)`. If it indeed does expect a string, you could try to serialize your results, e.g. JSON.